# WebProxy and Authentication on Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista, proxy

I am talking to a webservice via a webrequest, I am behind a proxy that requires authentication.

What I would like to do is piggyback off the IE / Control Panel settings but I am having some difficulty...

if I do this, all is fine...

```
  WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(@"http://my.secret.address:8080");
  proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
  WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

What I really want to do is simply this...

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(); // Subsequent webrequest call Fails with a "Unable to connect to remote server" error message.
```

I really do not want to have to specify the proxy address, as it is not the same for all users. In fact some won't even be behind a proxy. I just want to use the IE /Control Panel settings. Oh I am using Vista in case that makes a difference, and also the proxy settings in th econtrol panel / IE are using an auto config file (proxy.pac file)

Edit: So succinctly. How do I use the IE / Control Panel proxy settings. Including when using an Auto configuration file ?

Further Edit:

Ok, I think I have narrowed down the problem to the Auto Config thing. If I have the proxy address explicitly set in the dialog I can use the .GetSystemWebProxy() settings...but (like in my case) if I am using an Auto Config pac file, I have this issue.

[alt text http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5635/57955210.jpg](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5635/57955210.jpg)

Comment: What *exactly* is the question?

Comment: umm, I thought it was clear..I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sigh, well after more investigation I fixed this problem just to get a different one....

The fix is to create the WebProxy with the .pac Uri

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(@"http://blahblah/proxy.pac);
```

Easy peasy...

So now I am getting through the proxy, but the Proxy server is messing with my request and the web service is barffing. (Note it doesn't do it if I am specific about the proxy address....sigh)

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 1.0, you could use:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
```

In 2.0, DefaultWebProxy is *supposed* to contain the IE proxy settings by default, so this method is obsolete.

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/2542.aspx has more information.

**UPDATE**: Apperently the .NET 2.0 method is now;

```
WebRequest.DefaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx

Comment: I was about to reply the same thing. This obsolete method does not work in my circumstances. I am starting to think that the .GetSystemWebProxy() just does the same thing as this call.

Comment: But then what kind of exception does it throw?  And GetSystemWebProxy is the new one, so I think there must have been some kind of change.

Comment: The error is in the question above "Unable to connect to remote server"